# What format should my site-map be in?

Tags: mysql, html, seo

I am creating a site-map with all urls on my site!

I have a classifieds site, so I'm using a mysql database.

What format should I create the 'static' page which contains all the urls and is 'auto incremented' for each ad created on my site ?

Thanks

Comment: are you creating a site map for google?

Comment: The term "sitemap" is actually used to mean two things:

Is this an HTML sitemap that would be visible to people browsing your site?  Or are you creating a sitemap exclusively to help search engines find  your content?

Comment: No, I want to create a sitemap for SE... I got confused at first as the term has two meanings...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're creating a sitemap for google and not your users read this...

http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156184

Answer (score 2):

I'd checkout [sitemaps.org](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.php) for details of the format of the files.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a dynamic page accessing your database and renbering the result in a html `<ul>` list